# How to assert Errors instead of Exception in phpunit?

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit, assert, expected-exception

In my unit test I want to caught if an [ArithmeticError](https://php.net/manual/en/class.arithmeticerror.php) has been thrown, just like for an Exception using the @expectedException tag.

Unfortunally, it seems that phpunit recognize only Exceptions and not Errors.

Anyone know how to test for expected errors, instead excpetions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Using `error_reporting(2);` in a TestCase's setUp method ensure phpunit can convert all Errors in Exceptions. **I tried various error reporting levels, but only the one above works** (see the [error reporting levels](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php)). In this case was simple to me:

```
class DivisionTest extends TestCase
{
  public function setUp() : void
  {
    $this->division = new Division;
    error_reporting(2);
  }

  /**
   * When divide by zero (x / 0) should throw an Error.
   * @expectedException DivisionByZeroError
   */
  public function testDivedByZeroThrowException()
  {
    // Act
    $result = $this->division->run(0, 5); // 5 : 0
  }
}
```

Now this test returns Success!!! For more information visit [Testing PHP Errors](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html?highlight=exception#testing-php-errors).